# Cannot use namespace "OktaAuthService" as a type

Tags: angular, okta

Module '"../../../../node_modules/@okta/okta-angular/okta-angular"' has no exported member 'OktaAuthService'

I have a problem implementing Okta in my Angular  project

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you were using Okta Angular 4.0 when you encountered this error. In 4.0, `OktaAuthService` was replaced with `OktaAuth` from the okta-auth-js library. See the [Okta Angular 3.x to 4.x migration guide](https://github.com/okta/okta-angular/blob/master/MIGRATING.md#from-version-3x-to-4x) for changes.

I migrated one of our Angular samples this week. [This PR](https://github.com/okta-samples/okta-angular-sample/pull/219) will help you see the changes necessary.

Comment: thanks! This should be marked as the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was a confliction of versions between angular and Okta;
Just downgraded Okta version like this:

"@okta/okta-angular": "^3.2.2",
"@okta/okta-signin-widget": "^5.10.1",

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it is working for me. I downgraded okta-angular version to `"@okta/okta-angular": "^3.2.2"`.